# Run code and get result before render UI ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In React functional component, sometimes I want to call API to get data for conditional rendering in ReactJS, for example, when enter a user profile, I want to call API to get data of whether I followed this user or not to display whether 'Unsubscribe' or 'Subscribe' button.

If I use useEffect() it won't work like what I expected. Maybe there is some way to do this but the next problem I think is that how to execute call API function synchronously to definitely return the data for UI rendering?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.